# Is there type of error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would ask about java script error, is there type of error like php
or others,

example: In php we have notice, and Parse Error ..etc notice will not
be stop php execute, but parse will be stop execute php code
directly..

now is there js error like this, or what is the js classification
error .. I know we can handle error by try, catch ..,but is there
error in js was stooped script and others will not stop execute script

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there error in js was stooped script and others will not stop execute script

Not except for parsing/syntax errors, no.

JavaScript has exceptions. An exception exits the code in which it is thrown, and the code that called that, and so on until it's caught. If it isn't caught, then all currently-running functions are terminated and the error is logged to the web console.

So an exception (either one you throw explicitly or one that happens as a by-product of something you do) will either terminate all running functions (if not caught) or only terminate some code (if caught).

For example:

```
function foo() {
    try {
        bar(0);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Caught exception");
    }
}
function bar(a) {
    if (a <= 0) {
        throw new Error("'a' cannot be <= 0");
    }
    console.log("bar: a = " + a);
}

foo();
```

There, the code in `bar` following the exception is not run (we don't see `"bar: a = 0"`) because an exception was throw, terminating `bar`. But `foo`'s code continues, in the `catch` block, because `foo` caught the exception.

JavaScript is unusual in that you can throw anything, including a string, a number, etc. But if you want useful information, you usually throw `Error`:

```
throw new Error("Optional message here");
```

Since what you throw can be anything, you might be thinking there's a way to catch only certain things, but that's not the case. `catch` catches **any** exception that was thrown. So:

```
try {
    throw "foo";
}
catch (e) {
}

try {
    throw new Error();
}
catch (e)
}

try {
    throw 42;
}
catch (e)
}
```

Note that those `catch` clauses are identical; they catch **anything** that was thrown. Of course, you can then inspect what you got and re-throw:

```
try {
    // ...some code here that may throw any of several things...
}
catch (e)
    if (typeof e === "string") {
        // Handle it here
    }
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

There we only handle exceptions that are strings, and not ones that are numbers, `Error` objects, etc.

You can create your own derived versions of `Error` if you like, although it's a bit more of a pain than it ought to be:

```
function MySpecificError(msg) {
  this.message = msg;
  try {
    throw new Error();
  }
  catch (e) {
    this.stack = e.stack;
  }
}
MySpecificError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
MySpecificError.prototype.constructor = MySpecificError;
```

Then:

```
throw new MySpecificError("Something went wrong.");
```

Note that we had to fill in the code in `MySpecificError` to create the stack trace. (Also note that not all engines provide a stack trace, but if they do, this lets you use it.)

Some engines provide a few error types out of the box:

- `Error`
- `RangeError` (something was out of range)
- `ReferenceError` (but usually that's something you'd let the engine throw)
- `TypeError` (again)
- `SyntaxError` (again)

---

Finally, it's worth noting that several things that would cause exceptions in other environments don't in JavaScript, mostly around math. For instance:

```
var result = 10 / 0;
```

In many non-JavaScript environments, that results in a runtime error (division by zero). In JavaScript, it doesn't; `result` gets the value `Infinity`.

Similarly:

```
var x = Number("I am not a number");
```

or

```
var x = parseInt("I am not a number", 10);
```

...doesn't throw a parsing error, it sets `x` to `NaN` ("not a number").

Comment: thank you mate, 

this is very nice answer, but about type of error, thats mean all the error in js have a same type ..and we can handle it by try, catch only ?

Comment: @AnisHikmatAbu-hmiad: Yes, sorry, I meant to say: They don't all have the same type (you can throw anything), but `catch` catches *any* exception that was thrown. It's not like some other languages where you can catch some and not others. Meant to call that out, I'll add something now.

Comment: @AnisHikmatAbu-hmiad: I've added the bit I wanted to add now.

Comment: you can use `instanceof` if you want to know whether the error is an Error, a  SyntaxError or a MySpecificError.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Javascript errors can have types, and there is a standard error type hierarchy.  You can also write your code to "throw" things that are not error objects.

<sup>(In fact, since the `catch` clause in Javascript / ECMAScript does not discriminate based on the type of the exception, exception handling tends to be rather crude; i.e. "catch all errors" and then attempt to recover.  Hence, to a first order, it doesn't matter what you `throw`.)</sup>

The ECMAScript 5.1 spec says that syntax errors are "early errors" and that they *must* be reported before the program is executed.  An exception to this is syntax errors detected in code being run using `eval`.  However, the spec doesn't say how early errors are to reported, or what happens afterwards.  (At least, I don't think it does ...)

I believe that a common strategy for a Javascript parser/compiler/interpreter to skip to the enclosing block, and replace the affected code with code that throws an exception (e.g. `SyntaxError`) if it is run.

References:

- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/error-recovery.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError
- [EcmaScript 5.1 - Errors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-16)

Comment: thank you mate.. Im learn too much from you and other answer, thanks for help